# Why isn't my if statement working inside of my switch statement?

Tags: c#

I need to make a program that grades student tests. I'm trying to find a way to use loops and not write out a lot of  variables. I thought I could use a `switch` statement then put an `if` statement inside of it.

For example, in the loop, if the student's answer for question one equals `c` then add 1 to the counter, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

```cs
   int Counter = 0;
    string StudAns;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Students answer for question {0}: ");
        StudAns = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (i)
        {
            case '1':
                if (StudAns == "c")
                {
                    Counter++;
                }
                
           
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are two errors: Every switch case needs to have a break statement. Then i is a number but you treat it as a char. Because there is an automatic conversion between int and char the code compiles but it will never hit the case '1' becase case '1' is equal to the ascii value of '1'  (49)

Comment: Omg thank you so much I fixed it and it works now so thanks alot

Comment: You've got yourself a For/Case anti-pattern there.  See http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm , https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348682/what-is-the-for-case-antipattern ,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence

Answer (score 4):

There are many problems with your code, but answering the question itself, `i` is a number, not a character. Change your switch case to the following instead:

```
case 1: // not '1'
```

That will highlight the next problem, you're missing a `break;` before your default case.

Comment: Ah ...good catch on the case...